# How to make this longan tree bear fruit?

Tags: fruit-trees

[image: this is my longan tree]

This is image on internet which the trees bear fruit can I make my tree which same size bear fruits
[image: bear fruits longan tree]

Comment: How old is your tree, and how much sun does your tree get?

Comment: I think 1 year old more, it gets indirect sunlight as the picture looks like about 10hours everyday

Comment: Gotta be a 3-year plant, but more sun and mild fertilizer couldn't hurt to push flowers and fruit.